# printer problems

Tags: additional-drivers

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to the 20 version and now the printer won't work right. I have the latest driver from HP---the printer is an Officejet Pro 8610 and works fine with all the older versions of Ubuntu.  Have run the "sudo apt-get install hplip-gui" and that is about all I know to do.  Can print one copy at a time but sometimes it will stop in the middle of a page and never go any further.  Cannot print multiple copies.  When I click on the printer in the settings , it says there is no driver, what now.

Ubuntu needs to come up with an update solution for this problem

Comment: Ubuntu 20 implies Ubuntu Core 20 (or another *yy* release), which is a different product to the *yy.mm* format 20.04 for example.  Please clarify are you talking about the standard *yy.mm* product, or the specialist releases using *yy* format as you have written (they are different products).

Comment: As for your statement "Ubuntu needs to come up"; have you filed a bug?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)   Were you using the Ubuntu driver? as you indicate you were using the "*latest driver from HP*" meaning the fix actually needs to be performed by HP themselves (and Ubuntu can't do anything; have you filed the bug with them?)   Qt4 & python2 reached EOL in 2019 so some 3rd party packages (inc. HP) that relied on them needed changing...